# How to change a class component (input, conditional) to functional component with useState - hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, conditional-statements, react-hooks

I'd like to change a working class component into a functional component. It's basically an input field that should:

1) Dynamically display/Mirror whatever you enter (see the h1 below the form)
2) Show "no data provided" if nothing entered

The error message says "Failed to compile ... unexpected use of "event""

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function Exercise2() {
    const [input, inputChange] = useState({firstName: ""})

    const handleChange = () => {
        inputChange({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    let display
    if (useState.firstName != "") {
        display = useState.firstName
    } else {
        display = "no data provided!"
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    placeholder="Enter your data here"
                    value = "input.firstName"
                    onChange = "handleChange"
                />
            </form>

            <h1>{display}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Exercise2
```

Can someone point out what I am missing (without altering the code structure too much since I want to stick to my beginners logic). Thx

PS: this was my class component which worked perfectly and that I am trying to translate

```
class Exercise1 extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            firstName:""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange (event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        let display
        if(this.state.firstName != "") {
            display=this.state.firstName
        } else {
            display="no data provided!"
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <form>Input: 
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="firstName" 
                        placeholder = "Enter your data here!"
                        value={this.state.firstName}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </form>

                <h1>{display}</h1>              
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `event` param: `const handleChange = (event) => {`

Comment: @Andy updated this part to this but still not working `handleChange (event) => {
  this.setState({
   [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the key things are:

1) Not placing the variable/method names in curly braces

```
value={input.firstName}
onChange={handleChange}
```

2) Not including an `event` arg in your `handleChange` method:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
```

Here I've corrected those problems and also changed how the display is being rendered to make it more "React-like".

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Exercise2() {

  // Here you're setting state and assigning an object to it with
  // once property: `firstName`
  const [ input, inputChange ] = useState({ firstName: '' });

  const handleChange = (event) => {

    // The click event has been passed in.
    // `target` is the element that's been clicked. We're just grabbing the name and
    // value from it. We're assigning the name `firstName` as a dynamic property key name
    // (we wrap it in square braces), and assign the value to it. We do that because we want to
    // update the `firstName` property in the state object.
    // Because state is an object (and we might eventually have other properties in there
    // that we want to keep when we update this value) we return an object containing all
    // the properties of input, and the new dynamic property
    inputChange({ ...input, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  // `input` is an object with a firstName property.
  // We can destructure the `firstName` property from the state to make
  // it easier to work with
  const { firstName } = input;
console.log(input)
  let display;

  if (firstName.length) {
    display = firstName;
  } else {
    display = "no data provided!";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="Enter your data here"
          value={firstName}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>

      <h1>{display}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Exercise2 />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Hey @Andy ... this works. Couple of questions to truly understand what you did:

1. Why do I have to put the variables / methods in curly braces wheres as in the class componenet I didn't need to?

2. What exactly does const { firstName } = input; do?

3. Could you insert (commented out) the if else statement instead of the onliner? Thx

Comment: 1). You _did_ have the method/variable names in curly braces (`onChange={this.handleChange}, for example`), and 2) That's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and allows you to pull out data from objects and arrays more easily.

Comment: thx @andy I look into destrcuturing .... very last question: Can you explain in an English sentence what happens at the follwing part? What does event even mean here and are target.name and target value standard syntax to get input entries?

` const handleChange = (event) => {
     inputChange({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
 }

   const { firstName } = input;`

Comment: I've put the if/else statement back as requested.

Comment: And I've added some commentary to the code @Stephan-thecurious

Comment: Thank you @Andy. I will need to look into destrcuturing because this part I don't get yet. Would there be any other (easier way) to express the same?

Comment: You used `input.firstName` which is fine, and the traditional way of accessing the property. Destructuring simply allows you to access that property _and assign it to its own variable_. It just saves on typing. [Here's your code without the destructuring](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-shockley-i1njz).

Comment: appreciate your effort and time. Thank you big time

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function Exercise2() {
const [input, inputChange] = useState({firstName: ""})

const handleChange = (event) => {
    inputChange({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}

let display
if (input.firstName !== "") {
    display = input.firstName
} else {
    display = "no data provided!"
}

return (
    <div>
        <form>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                placeholder="Enter your data here"
                value = {display}
                onChange = {handleChange}
            />
        </form>

        <h1>{display}</h1>
    </div>
)
}

export default Exercise2
```

Comment: that doesn't work. it neither mirrors my entry nor displays "no data provided"

Comment: I changed the code, just saw the useState usage after seeing your comment sorry. Can you check now?

Comment: close, but now it has "no data provided!" also as placeholder instead of the placeholder "Enter your data here"

Comment: Then we should remove the value = {display} from the form.

Answer (score 0):

You're syntax seems to be wrong, you should try something like

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function Exercise2() {
    const [formData, changeFormData] = useState({firstName: ""});

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        changeFormData({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }



    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    placeholder="Enter your data here"
                    value={formData.firstName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </form>
            <h1>{formData.firstName !== "" ? formData.firstName : 'no data provided!'}</h1>
//the above line is a ternary operator, basically it reads as if( input.firstName !== "") return input.firstName : else return 'no data provided!'
        </div>
    )
}

export default Exercise2
```

Comment: it doesn't work. There is an input field but it neither mirrors nor displays the missing data message upon entry / when no entry

Comment: Sorry @Stephan-thecurious I have updated it now, apparently you can't use input as a state because it's a private JS variable, I changed it to formData it should work now

Comment: I would also recommend you spread the current state in the state update function , so if you had other fields like email or password it won't mutate the entire state
something like ```
changeFormData({...formdata, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}) 
```
This basically means if the formData is changed, maintain the rest of the unchanged data and change the new one